# how to extract the contextual words of a token in python

Tags: python

Actually i want to extract the contextual words of a specific word. For this purpose i can use the n-gram in python but the draw back of this is that it slides the window by one but i only need the contextual words of a specific word. E.g. my file is like this

```
 IL-2  
 gene  
 expression  
 and  
 NF-kappa  
 B  
 activation  
 through  
 CD28  
 requires  
 reactive  
 oxygen  
 production  
 by  
 5-lipoxygenase  
 .
```

mean each token on every line. now i want to extract the surrounding words of each  e.g. through and requires are the surrounding words of **"CD28"**. I write a python code but did not worked and generating an error of **ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list**.
My code is

```
import re;
import nltk;
file=open("C:/Python26/test.txt");
contents= file.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents)
f=open("trigram.txt",'w');
for l in tokens:
    print tokens[l],tokens[l+1]
f.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, list.index(x) : Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x.

```
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index('bar')
1
```

In your code, the variable 'word' is populated using range of integers not by actual contents. so we can't directly use 'word' in the list.index() function.

```
>>> print lines.index(1)
ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

change your code like this :

```
file="C:/Python26/tokens.txt";
f=open("trigram.txt",'w');

with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();

for word in range(1,len(lines)-1):
    f.write(lines[word-1].strip()+"\t"+lines[word].strip()+"\t"+lines[word+1].strip())

f.close()
```

Comment: Hi @Shaheen Gul,  if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  it by clicking the check-mark . This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understood what you want to do, but, I'll do my best.

If you want to process words with python there is a library called NLTK which means Natural Language Toolkit.

You may need to tokenize a sentence or a [document](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#reading-local-files).

```
import nltk


def tokenize_query(query):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(query)

f = open('C:/Python26/tokens.txt')
raw = f.read()
tokenize_query(raw)
```

We can also read a file one line at a time using a for loop:

```
f = open('C:/Python26/tokens.txt', 'rU')
for line in f:
    print(line.strip())
```

r means 'read' and U means 'universal', if you are wondering.

strip() is just cutting '\n' from the text.

The context may be provided by [wordnet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) and all its functions.
I guess you should use synsets with the word's pos (part of speech).

A synset is sort of a synonyms list in a semantic way.

NLTK can provide you some others nice features like sentiment analysis and similarity between synsets.

Comment: I have already tokenized txt file, which i m using for extracting new information. but i want to extract the surrounding words of each word (e.g. previous word, word, next word) in that file where word is current targeted word. Every word is on the new line in txt file

Comment: When you tokenize, at least in NLTK, you get a list object. Remember that you can retrieve elements form it with its position. list[i], list[i+1].

Comment: I tried ur directions but it caused an error that is                                          TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str                                                         I edited the code plz check that

Answer (score 0):

```
file="C:/Python26/tokens.txt";
f=open("trigram.txt",'w');

with open(file,'r') as rf:
lines = rf.readlines();
for word in range(1,len(lines)-1):
    f.write(lines[word-1].strip()+"\t"+lines[word].strip()+"\t"+lines[word+1].strip())
    f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Please describe how this answers the question. What was the problem that you have overcome? (Low quality review queue)

Comment: This code gave me the exact answer of extracting the previous and next token of a specific token. problem was basically in loop . This answer exactly gave me previous word and next word of a current targeted word in a list,

Comment: Then [edt] your answer to include this description. Why do you just added another answer? You can edit the other answer into this answer and then delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

This code also gives the same result

```
import nltk;
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import word_tokenize
file = open("C:/Python26/tokens.txt");
contents=file.read();
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents);
f_tri = open("trigram.txt",'w');               
trigram = ngrams(tokens,3)
for t in trigram:
    f_tri.write(str(t)+"\n")
f_tri.close()
```